# DropDownList do not run the code behind

Tags: asp.net

hy,
i configured `dropdownlist`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_filter1" runat="server" Width="120px" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
                                        DataTextField="PLC" DataValueField="PLC" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_filter1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

and i want that when i choose a value from the `DropDownList` an event will happen

but for somereason the code behind do not run.

what is the problem in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put `AutoPostBack="true"` for the ddl?

For your code would be:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_filter1" runat="server" Width="120px" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
      DataTextField="PLC" DataValueField="PLC" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_filter1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `Autopostback` to true.

Example:

```
<asp:DropDownList   
             ID="DropDownList1"  
             runat="server"  
             AutoPostBack="true"  
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"  
             >  
             <asp:ListItem>HyperLink</asp:ListItem>  
             <asp:ListItem>PasswordRecovery</asp:ListItem>  
             <asp:ListItem>PlaceHolder</asp:ListItem>  
             <asp:ListItem>LoginName</asp:ListItem>  
             <asp:ListItem>Label</asp:ListItem>  
        </asp:DropDownList>
```